# Aging Report MDX query issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Below is my `MDX` query to generate aging report. I want to use a named `SET` 
inside a calculated measure. I am getting this error:

> Query (3, 1) The  function expects a tuple set expression for the 1
>   argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Can this be resolved?

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    {'FILTER(
          [Cheque Detail Fact Keys].[Cheque Master ID].[Cheque Master ID]
         ,[Measures].[Paid Amt]<>0
       )'
    } 
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      ClosingPeriod
      (
        [Cal Date].[Month].[Month]
       ,[Cal Date].[Month].[All]
      )
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[0-30] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(1) : [x].Item(0).Lag(0)
     ,Count(Cnt) //[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[31-60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(2) : [x].Item(0).Lag(1)
     ,Count(Cnt) //[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[>60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      NULL : [x].Item(0).Lag(4)
     ,Count(Cnt)  //[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[0-30]
   ,[Measures].[31-60]
   ,[Measures].[>60]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```

Comment: do let me know if my code worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just the first section of your script. Why are you using a string? Try deleting the apostrophies and just add in `.MEMBERS` for clarity:

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    {FILTER(
          [Cheque Detail Fact Keys].[Cheque Master ID].[Cheque Master ID].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Paid Amt]<>0
       )
    } 
   ...
   ...
```

The error message seems a bit mysterious but I believe that the curly braces are a function themselves - they convert any members inside them into a set. So you have effectively written this `{<some string>}` but the curly brackets are expecting something that can be a set.

I get the same error message when running the following AdvWrks script:

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    {'FILTER(
          [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] > 10000
       )'
    } 
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,[Cnt] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

To use a count of `Cnt` in the following measures you can create a measure but I don't think this will be context aware as the set is evaluated before anything else:

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    {FILTER(
          [Cheque Detail Fact Keys].[Cheque Master ID].[Cheque Master ID]
         ,[Measures].[Paid Amt]<>0
       )
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Master Count]  AS 
    [Cnt].count
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      ClosingPeriod
      (
        [Cal Date].[Month].[Month]
       ,[Cal Date].[Month].[All]
      )
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[0-30] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(1) : [x].Item(0).Lag(0)
     ,[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[31-60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(2) : [x].Item(0).Lag(1)
     ,[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[>60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      NULL : [x].Item(0).Lag(4)
     ,[Measures].[Master Count] 
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[0-30]
   ,[Measures].[31-60]
   ,[Measures].[>60]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```

Comment: Refer the calculated measure for >60 days. Need to use Count (Cnt) (SET) instead of SUM for the more than 60 days. How to use count measure?

Comment: Can you create an `AdvWks` example for me to play with?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to pass a string to a set. You need to convert the string to a set first using the `StrToSet` function. Also as told by @whytheq, you don't need the curly braces.

Try replacing

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    {'FILTER(
          [Cheque Detail Fact Keys].[Cheque Master ID].[Cheque Master ID]
         ,[Measures].[Paid Amt]<>0
       )'
    }
```

with this-->

```
WITH 
  SET [Cnt] AS 
    StrToSet('FILTER(
          [Cheque Detail Fact Keys].[Cheque Master ID].[Cheque Master ID]
         ,[Measures].[Paid Amt]<>0
       )'
     )
```

Also the correct way to use the `COUNT` function is `<<SomeSet>>.COUNT`, **NOT** `COUNT(<<SomeSet>>)`

Answer (score 0):

The [Cnt] set looks expensive...is that based on a fact table? If so, what's the granularity?

Perhaps you can add a calculated field in the DSV for the base table of the measure group (e.g. IIF(Paid Amt <> 0, 1, 0) ) and then create a SUM-based measure on the field. Then your query becomes...

```
WITH  
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      ClosingPeriod
      (
        [Cal Date].[Month].[Month]
       ,[Cal Date].[Month].[All]
      )
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[0-30] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(1) : [x].Item(0).Lag(0)
     ,[Measures].[NonZero Check Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[31-60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [x].Item(0).Lag(2) : [x].Item(0).Lag(1)
     ,[Measures].[NonZero Check Count] 
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[>60] AS 
    Sum
    (
      NULL : [x].Item(0).Lag(4)
     ,[Measures].[NonZero Check Count] 
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[0-30]
   ,[Measures].[31-60]
   ,[Measures].[>60]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [My Cube];
```

Comment: SET(Cnt) is based on Dimension table